# Understand the definition of set $C = \{x : \exists~A (A \in F \rightarrow x \in A )\}$ where $F = \{(1,2,3), (2), (1,2)\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Given set $F =  \{(1,2,3), (2), (1,2)\}$.

Let $C = \{x :  \exists~A (A \in F \rightarrow x \in A )\}$

I am not able to understand what $C$ means ?

Comment: Are the elements of $F$ permutations?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Elements of set F are sets.

Comment: @JessicaGriffin: So really $F=\big\{\{1,2,3\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\big\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes that is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication $A\in F\to x\in A$ is equivalent to the disjunction $A\notin F\lor x\in A$. The statement $\exists A\,(A\notin F)$ is clearly true, so $\exists A\,(x\notin F\lor x\in A)$ is also true no matter what $x$ is, and therefore the equivalent statement $\exists A\,(A\in F\to x\in A)$ is true no matter what $x$ is. Thus, $C$ is the proper class of all sets and is not a set at all.

Comment: C = { x | there exists at least one set A such that ($x \in A if A \in F $) }.

Comment: Not sure $x$ is meant to be a set, rather than single value

Comment: What does $x \in A$ has to do with $x \in C$ ?

Comment: That's exactly **the** question. This answer show that _nothing_.)

Comment: @JessicaGriffin: Take $A=\varnothing$. Then $A\notin F$, so $A\in F\to x\in A$ is vacuously true **no matter what** $x$ **is**. If $C$ were defined as $\{x:\exists A\in F\,(x\in A)\}$, then $C$ would be $$\bigcup F=\{1,2,3\}\cup\{2\}\cup\{1,2\}=\{1,2,3\}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If A is $\phi$ then it becomes C = {x | x \in {}}

Comment: @JessicaGriffin: No, it does not. $A$ is a bound variable, and $C$ is $\{x:\exists A\,(A\in F\to x\in A)\}$, and $A=\varnothing$ is simply an example of a set that makes $A\in F\to x\in A$ true **no matter what** $x$ **is**.

Comment: @JessicaGriffin No, the implication $A\to B$ is true exactly in two cases: 1) $A$ is false 2) $A=B=$ true. Here in the answer the set $A$ is taken that $A\not\in F$ so the implication is true irrespective of $x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What is english translation of set C you defined in your second last comment

Comment: @JessicaGriffin: You mean $\{x:\exists A\in F\,(x\in A)\}$? That’s that set of all $x$ such that $x$ is a member of some element of $F$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for help

Comment: @JessicaGriffin: You’re welcome.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you